# How to get user information with Google API PHP SDK

Tags: php, sdk, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to add a login option to my website for people with Google accounts. I have been able to implement this Facebook but having issues getting user account information with Google.

I am using the Google PHP SDK located here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($this->ci->config->item('client_id', 'google'));
$client->setClientSecret($this->ci->config->item('client_secret', 'google'));
$client->setRedirectUri($this->ci->config->item('callback_uri', 'google'));
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
$this->client->createAuthUrl();
```

But now how do I access the user's email address and other basic information?

I see in the Google PHP SDK a method called `getAccountInfo()` in the class `Google_Service_IdentityToolkit`. However, the parameter it requires is `postBody` but I am not sure how to get/build that.

Answer (score 19):

This will return a Google_Service_Oauth2_Userinfoplus object with the info you're probably looking for:

```
$oauth2 = new \Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
print_r($userInfo);
```

Where `$client` is an instance of `Google_Client`

Outputs:

```
Google_Service_Oauth2_Userinfoplus Object
(
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
            [familyName] => family_name
            [givenName] => given_name
            [verifiedEmail] => verified_email
        )

    [email] => 
    [familyName] => 
    [gender] => 
    [givenName] => 
    [hd] => 
    [id] => 123456
    [link] => https://plus.google.com/123456
    [locale] => en-GB
    [name] => someguy
    [picture] => https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-q1Smh9d8d0g/AAAAAAAAAAM/AAAAAAAAAAA/3YaY0XeTIPc/photo.jpg
    [verifiedEmail] => 
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Also note that you need to request the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope as well.

Comment: Upvote. Do you know how can I get some additional info from user? i.e his phone number, his address etc ..! Should I use any specific library?

Comment: Great solution. One technical tho...The basic sign-in scopes to be set in Google_Client should be just 'email' and / or 'profile' (depending on what info do you need) since some time ago. The 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' one is deprecated, but kept for backwards compatibility, I think. More info on official website https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in

Comment: This API is Deprecated. You have to switch to the Google_Client

Comment: @PeterFox can you update this thread w/ a new answer then? Would really help as this response still comes up.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to get this info by constructing a Google_Service_OAuth2 object, passing in the Google_Client as a paramater, then get the user info from there.

```
$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userInfo = $oauth2->userinfo;
```

Comment: The cases seem to have changed since you posted this answer. It's now `Google_Service_Oauth2` (lowercase a) and `userinfo` (lowercase i)

Comment: @antriver You literally resolved my entire problem. With Wamp it didn't matter on the case sensitivity, when I moved it to lamp it crashed. So linux is OCD and windows don't care.